# Why does maven-release-plugin uploads build information? And can it be removed?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

When using the maven-release-plugin to release an artifact onto a repository, the entire pom is copied. This includes sections build and reporting.

I can understand that deployement information is propagated since dependencies of a project by the same creators are likely to be deployed on the same servers, but, for non-pom artifact, I don't understand the point of having the build information.

Is it possible to create a release stripped of this information?

Comment: You mean, non-java artifacts?

Comment: I mean non-pom. For pom artifacts, it makes sense since they are used to configure other artifacts. For Java artifacts, it makes no sense since they are not reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the flatten-maven-plugin

https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/

I copied the relevant plugin configuration from the website above.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!--<version>1.1.0</version>-->
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <!-- enable flattening -->
      <execution>
        <id>flatten</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>flatten</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <!-- ensure proper cleanup -->
      <execution>
        <id>flatten.clean</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I strips the POM from all unnecessary information.

Comment: Superbe! That is exactly what I was looking for!